# How to republish image to multiple topics with CameraInfoManager?

Tags: ros, camera-info-manager, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
My program takes the capture image from a webcam and dividing it into 4 images by splitting the main capture.
I want to publish those 4 images in a 4 different topics in the same ros package, same cpp file, but when I try to do that with creating 4 different camera_info_manager I get the error:

```
Tried to advertise a service that is already advertised in this node [/camera/set_camera_info]
```

Any ideas how to solve my issue and how to create 4 different rostopics ?
thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/273490/how-to-republish-image-to-multiple-topics-with-camerainfomanager?/) by [omrikoresh](https://answers.ros.org/users/31812/omrikoresh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-10-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Create four different nodehandles with four different names:

```
ros::NodeHandle nh1("image1");
ros::NodeHandle nh1("image2");
...
```

And then create four ImageTransports and so on:

```
image_transport::ImageTransport it1(nh1);
image_transport::ImageTransport it2(nh2);
...
```

then you'll get four different camera_info topics:

```
/image1/camera_info
/image2/camera_info
...
```

Or skip having four different camera_infos, use a regular ImageTransport::Publisher instead of CameraPublisher, just publish the image from four publishers (building off of http://wiki.ros.org/image_transport/Tutorials/PublishingImages)  from the one ImageTransport but any subscriber should have camera_info remapped to the original source one.  Even if you are doing something like splitting the images where only every 4th image goes out on the 4th topic, a subscriber that cares about camera_infos will match it up with the right one and ignore the other three camera_infos that don't correspond to any received images (though some nodes will output some warnings about this, they should still function fine).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-10-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0